# Microphone and speech to text in Dialogflow ES messenger integration

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there any way in dialogflow ES messenger integration to enable microphone and speech to text ,like it is in the webdemo ? if yes please can you regard me how to do it and if no is there a way in the future for this to happen or is there a third party solution to do it?
please help :)
Best Regards!